# C# dynamically change iframe using post method

Tags: c#, iframe, post

I'm a newbie to iframe.
I have a page that needs to call an iframe at another subdomain passing lots of data.
I'm wondering if it's possible to submit the iframe call using a POST instead of GET.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have the same problem, have to post data and get a session token back. Did you resolve this? if so how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer I'm afraid is no. You can pass plenty of data in the querystring to the iFrame, but HTML doesn't support the semantics to POST to an iFrame.